# How do I prevent circular references in a hierarchy?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

The problem I am trying to solve is to prevent circular references not just between an immediate parent and child, but I also want to ensure that a new child is not already used as a parent somewhere in the hierarchy of records.

I thought I might solve the problem by intercepting the assignment of a parent before executing the code,
    self.parent = maybe_the_wrong_choice
and then do important validation before saving the change.

Am I on the right path? If so, how do I grab the old value of an attribute in my Model validation (e.g. self.old_parent) and compare it with the new parent (self.parent) before saving the record?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Could you provide more information, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the old parent by self.parent_was and new parent by self.parent.

Comment: Let me clarify my question by means of an example:

Comment: Let me clarify my question by means of an example: 

Level 1:           A
Level 2:    A1   A2  A3
Level 3:    A11  A12   A13   …   A31  A32
Level 4:    A111 ...

The above hierarchy shows that A is a parent of A1, and A3 is a parent of A32
Now, consider the following scenarios:
- A11.parent = A3   # Not good because A11 already has a parent (A1)
- A14 = Category.create!(name: 'A14')
- A14.parent = A1   # This is good because A14.parent was equal to nil
- A31.parent = A14  # Not good because A31 already has a parent (A3)
- A.parent = A11    # Not good because A already has children